# Data Filter Shows Nothing To Filter On

Tags: excel, excel-2007, filtering

I have imported a query into Excel, very straight-forward process.  The issue I am having is if I click the header row and say filter, if I select any of the filter arrows, their are no values to filter on?  What should I change so that I am able to filter on values in the columns?

Row 1 contains header, row 2 contains data --- however their are a few blank values returned in the data row(s) (I.E. row 2 and beyond)

Here is a link to a garbage data workbook showing the issue.
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Ar44iHLPsMUzRNbjJhWG9CSGM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you somehow have a blank, hidden row under the header row?

Comment: Some of the rows will contain a blank value.

Comment: Is everything actually stuffed into column A and it only looks like the rest of the columns are populated due to text spill-over? If you select columnA and run a Text-to-Columns do you see the rest of the data?

Comment: @Jeeped - I have tabbed through my workbook and verified data is actually present in Columns A - V (no spillage)

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. This is very odd behavior indeed. Is there anyway you can post a redacted copy of the workbook (that still exhibits the rogue behavior) to a public share and post the URL link back here?

Comment: Do you have to do it necessarily in Excel 2007? It looks like filtering and sorting works just fine in the Google Sheets, so maybe you could use Sheets instead.

Comment: Wow. Just Wow. I've never seen this before. It would appear to be a malformed XLSX creation from an external program. You appear to have a second filter range hidden. Select any of the cell below the first row and click Data ► Data Tools ► Filter to expose it.

Comment: @Jan - yes it must remain in Excel 2007

Comment: @Jeeped is their anyway to change the filter range to the top row or do you have any recommendations on how to force a filter to the top row?

Comment: I'll play with this a bit. Are you opposed to macro-based repair/interference?

Comment: I am up for anything to restore filtering to top row!

Comment: OK, it looks like that is actually a ListObject Table called *Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database*. Can you modify your import routine so that you bring in raw data instead of a structured table? Alternately could you forget about your header row and just bring hte structured table into a blank worksheet then rename the column header the way you want them?

Comment: @Jeeped - I will import the raw data as opposed to a structured table - not sure why it was imported as a structured table anyway.

Comment: @JorgeJones - Raw data is always preferred IMO. I've posted some details on this situation for kicks, giggles and the benefit of other users in this fairly unique situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data was imported as a ListObject table and held a header that was hidden with `.ListObjects.ShowHeaders = False`. To fix this, the header row must be exposed and then the worksheet's row 1 transferred into the table's header row.

Here is some quick code that repairs the data imported as a table for this situation.

```
Sub Repair_Import()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each lo In .ListObjects
            If Not lo.ShowHeaders Then _
                lo.ShowHeaders = True
            If Not IsNumeric(.Cells(2, 1)) Then
                .Rows(1).Copy Destination:=.Cells(2, 1)
                .Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            If Not lo.ShowAutoFilterDropDown Then _
                lo.ShowAutoFilterDropDown = True
        Next lo
    End With
End Sub
```

With A2 (or any cell in the actual List Object table) selected, That roughly translates to:

1. Table Tools ► Design ► Table Style Options ► Header Row
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>
2. Copy the first row of header labels. 
    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
3. Select A2 and paste.
    <sub><kbd>↓</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd></sub>
4. Select row 1 and delete, shifting up. 
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and finally <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>.
5. Table Tools ► Design ► Table Style Options ► Filter Button
    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd>

IMHO, a raw data import would have been better and allowed more individual customization on the user's end. 
This does depend on the table header's top-left cell being text based and that column being numerical but individual circumstances should be easily accommodated with minor editing.

As opened with hidden table header row.

[image: Hidden header row in imported table]

Turning on Data ► Data Tools ► Filter shows no values available to filter on.

[image: Hidden header row in imported table restricts filter options]

Using the context menu Table Tools ► Design ► Table Style Options ► show Header Row.

[image: Showing header row in imported table]

After running the repair macro.

[image: Worksheet columns headers transferred to imported table]

Values become available for filtering.

[image: Filter optionas available]

Comment: @pnuts - I had assumed that the OP wanted his/her original heading labels across row 1 and not the ones that came from the Access table.

Comment: @pnuts - My head hurts. I thought that was what I did.

Comment: @pnuts - Imports like this are often automated and repeated. I wanted to provide some auto-repair functionality. I suppose I should have added some manual repair instructions.

Comment: It works but I get an error of Object doesnt support his property or method when it hits the last If -- the ShowAutoFilterDropDown seems to be the culprit.

Comment: @JorgeJones - A ListObject can be other things than a table and you might have one that cannot posses the `.ShowAutoFilterDropDown` property. Due to the import automatically assigning a name for the table, I looped through all ListObjects on the worksheet. It is very possible that I looped into one that wasn't a table. TBH, that line was a bit of fluff anyways. Comment it out or removed it altogether.